# Cargo build includes path in output binary

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm using `cargo build` to compile my project.

However, for dependencies the full absolute path is logged in the outputbinary when using `strings` on the binary.

For example: `/home/evrey/.cargo/registry/src/test.net-2dcc6299db9ec823/winit-0.20.0-alpha6/src/platform_impl/linux/x11/window.rs`.

How can I remove the private paths from the compiled binary using `cargo build`?

Comment: Perhaps with the profile, `cargo build --profile name` , opt-level: 3 and debug: false, documentaion [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html) and [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html)

Comment: @Zeppi not working

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40552

Comment: In `Cargo.toml`, does `strip="debuginfo"` under `[profile.release]` work?

Comment: @BallpointBen, no.